# How to map ":f" to "1<c-g>"?

Tags: vim, mapping, key-bindings, ctrl

`:f[ile]` has similar feature as `<c-g>`. However, I want `:f` to print the full path of the current file which is `1<c-g>`'s job. The following config doesn't work: `nnoremap :f 1<c-g>`, the count 1 just ignored by vim and `:f` has nothing changed.

Comment: `:f` is command-line mode, so I don't think you can use `nnoremap` here.. also, I don't know how to change behavior of a command-line command...

Comment: how about `nnoremap <c-g> 1<c-g>` to get your desired behavior when you press `<c-g>` ?

Comment: @Sundeep thanks! I just find a [solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/1885). `cmap` for command line mapping. So `cnoremap f<enter> echo expand('%:p')<enter>` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map from command line to normal mode you can use:

```
cmap f normal 1<c-g>
```